# Mongoose find() returning irrelevant documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this one:

```
var WorkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  works: [{
    name:String,
    times:[{
      day:String,
      timeOfDay:[{
        startTime: Number,
        endTime: Number
      }],
      date: Date
    }],
    locations:[String]
  }],
  worker: {
     id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
     },
     username: String
  }
  },{timestamps: true}
);
```

I have saved a lot of document on this schema. Now, i want to find the documents which has `name:'idle'`. I'm using `Worker.find({'works.name':req.body.name})` but it's not giving me the exact documents i want and giving irrelevant documents. But in MongoDb Compass, this exact line is finding the desired documents.
How do i find the values in mongoose?

Comment: what irrelevant information are you getting ?

Comment: Some documents that doesn't have name:'idle' in them.

Comment: Impossible, you may doing something wrong elsewhere

Comment: if some documents doesn't have 'name' parameter, are they supposed to be returned in the query?

Comment: if `req.body.name = null` then can be happen because then your query will be like `'works.name': null` so if any document has not `'works.name'` then return that document

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explained.